# Insert Blob data using stored procedure in DB2 by .net

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, db2

How can I insert blob data to DBB2 using stored procedure in .net?

When I insert blob data by sql string = `INSERT INTO tblDemo(IDFile,Content) values(?,?)`
and add DB2Parameters for DB2Command ==> Run ok

Then I write a stored procedure to insert into `tblDemo`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_ADD(v_IDFile GRAPHIC(10),
v_Content BLOB(2047M)) LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
   insert into tblDemo(IDFile,
    Content)
values(v_IDFile ,
    v_Content);
END
```

and run DB2Command, I get error:

> ERROR [57011] [IBM][DB2/NT] SQL0930N  There is not enough storage
>   available to process the statement.  SQLSTATE=57011

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must adjust the "[UDF Shared Memory](http://webdocs.caspur.it/ibm/udb-6.1/db2d0/db2d0229.htm#HDRCFG225)" (udf_mem_sz) setting.

Comment: Can you show comamnd to update udf_mem_sz? The command 

"db2 UPDATE DBM CFG USING udf_mem_sz 1024"
throw error:

SQL0104N  An unexpected token "1024" was found following "<identifier>".
Expected tokens may include:  "AGENTPRI".  SQLSTATE=42601

Comment: Which version of DB2 are you using?